# optimizing google protocol buffer

Tags: java, python, protocol-buffers

I'm new to google's protocol buffers and looking into some insight. I have a large object that is serialized in java which I am de-serializing in python. The upstream tells me that the file is serialized in about 4 to 5 seconds. Where it takes me 37 seconds to de-serialize. Any ideas on why it is such a huge difference besides hardware? are there ways I can speed up the de-serialization? Does Java perform better for this? I'm simply grabbing a serialized data file and using ParseFromString.

Thanks

UPDATE:- So just got back to this after a while and tried to deserialize the file using java. It took 4 seconds to deserialize a bigger file (56 m). Now this solves my problem with the performance however, I really am confused about the huge difference between the python and java, any insights?

Comment: Roughly how big (bytes) and complex (number of types) is this model? That sounds a **very** long time...

Comment: Also: does the speed vs size setting in .proto / protocol make any difference here?

Comment: If you're using big repeated fields of primitive types, make sure to set the `packed` option: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#optional

Comment: `ParseFromString` makes it sound like you're using the protobuf text format rather than the much faster byte format?

Comment: the serialized file is 20mb filled with complex repeated fields. Unfortunately I cant use packed option since the biggest fields complex repeated fields. as for ParseFromString  is there another way to parse the data in python?

Answer (score 2):

We can look forward to this amazing lib

```
http://kentonv.github.io/capnproto/
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Python protobuf deserialization is just pretty slow (as of 2013) compared to the other languages.